# Backup and restore development files?

Tags: backup, development, re-installation, ruby, rails

I started with Ubuntu with a small partition and I'm running out of space.

I'm planning to dump Windows altogether and use my full disk for Ubuntu (also, doing a clean install for once), but I need help before doing so because I have web development projects going on, which I'll need to continue after reinstalling.

I'm currently using Ruby, rvm, Heroku and git. My git repos are backed up in dropbox, but, how can I backup my ruby version, with rvm and heroku ssh keys?

And after reinstalling, how do I restore these configs in my new running system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can back up your ssh keys by creating a copy of the .ssh folder in your home folder. You can backup your Heroku credentials by creating a copy of the .heroku folder in your home folder. It would also be wise to backup any gpg keys you have by creating a copy of ~/.gnupg if it exists. To restore these on a new installation, copy them back into your home folder.

From the command line you could run:

```
cp -r ~/.ssh ~/.heroku ~/.gnupg BACKUP_FOLDER
```

replacing BACKUP_FOLDER with the path to the folder you are backing up to.

I'm not sure about rvm, but you could look for a .rvm folder in your home folder. If there isn't any you could search for rvm files/folders:

```
find ~ -path "*rvm*"
```